# Canonical form representation of a Linear Gaussian CPD

Tags: mathematical-physics, statistics

I'd like to know how a linear Gaussian conditional probability distribution can be represented to a canonical form.

For example, let X and Y be two sets of continuous variables, with |X| = n and |Y| = m. Let

p(Y | X) = *N*(Y | *a* + BX; C)

where *a* is a vector of dimension m, B is an m by n matrix, and C is an m by m matrix.

Comment: Would http://stats.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?